# Query using "LIMIT" still warns about result set with more than 10000 records

Tags: orientdb

I have a simple model where I have a **CLIENT** class. Nodes from **CLIENT** can have a relationship **OWS_MONEY_TO** to another **CLIENT**. That's it.
With this setup, I created 10 million **CLIENT** nodes and 50 million random relationships of **OWS_MONEY_TO** within random CLIENTS.

When I run this query:

```
MATCH
   {class:CLIENT, as:A}-OWS_MONEY_TO->{class:CLIENT, as:B}
RETURN A.name as Payer, B.name as Receiver limit 10
```

I hit this error:

```
Query 'SELECT FROM CLIENT' returned a result set with more than 10000 records.
Check if you really need all these records, or reduce the resultset by using a
LIMIT to improve both performance and used RAM
```

I'm using a limit already, as you may see, and I haven't been able to figure out how to get any result from this query.

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Thx

Comment: Thanks Michela. I'm using the Community Edition 2.2.33 which I downloaded 2 weeks ago or so.